# Detect duplicate pieces of text with hashing

Tags: hash, spam, text-analysis

I'm trying to detect similar pieces of text to stop spammers from posting the same pieces of spam with small alterations.

For this I'd like to use a hash instead of saving all sentences in a datastore. To save up room and make lookups fast.

I am hashing the entire text, without punctuations or weird characters, and compar hashes to find duplicate spam.

But as soon as the spammer adds a random value, the system fails.

Does anyone have a way to improve this system? I tried perceptual hashing, but that only seems to work good enough on large pieces of text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hashing is basically that, you will not detect 'similar' pieces of text using hashing algorithms because they are designed to change completely for two different test cases even if the difference is a comma. Avalanche effect :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect

Nice idea to delete punctuations/weird chars though. If you can find out where does the spammer add the value (at end-1 line for example) you can then cut out the text and hash from beginning to end-2 (just an idea). 
You can also hash keywords of the text (headline, products...)